# TFIDF calculating confusion

Tags: python, data-mining, text-processing, information-retrieval, tf-idf

I found the following code on the internet for calculating TFIDF:

```
https://github.com/timtrueman/tf-idf/blob/master/tf-idf.py
```

I added "1+" in the function def idf(word, documentList) so i won't get divided by 0 error:

```
return math.log(len(documentList) / (1 + float(numDocsContaining(word,documentList))))
```

But i am confused for two things:

1. I get negative values in some cases, is this correct?
2. I am confused with line 62, 63 and 64.

Code:

```
 documentNumber = 0
  for word in documentList[documentNumber].split(None):
       words[word] = tfidf(word,documentList[documentNumber],documentList)
```

Should TFIDF be calculated on the first document only?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. No. Tf-idf is tf, a non-negative value, times idf, a non-negative value, so it can never be negative. This code seems to be implementing the [erroneous definition of tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tf%E2%80%93idf&oldid=426828805) that's been on the Wikipedia for years (it's been [fixed](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Tf%E2%80%93idf&diff=436842968&oldid=426828805) in the meantime).

Comment: hmm i have to check that out.

Comment: i have corrected the formula, but i have one thing unclear about the second thing from the list above. Any hints?

Comment: @badc0re: I don't really get that code. Usually, you apply tf-idf to an entire corpus.

Comment: Another example why copying code from random github sites is not a good idea... it might be a broken copy from Wikipedia. :-)

Comment: no, i was just seeking for example implementation and i found this one.

Comment: I'm 5 years late, hopefully you still use SO. Why can't idf be -ve? The log of n < 1 is always -ve, and idf = log_e(Total number of documents / Number of documents with term t in it). Therefore, idf is very likely to be -ve. Anything I'm missing? P.S. On further inspection, it seems the user has left SO ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

If the word in question is contained in every document in the collection your 1+ change will result in a negative value. As 0 < (x / (1 + x)) < 1 holds for all x > 0. Which results in a negative logarithm.

In my opinion the correct IDF for a nonexistent word is infinite or undefined, but by adding 1+ to the denominator and the nominator a nonexistent word will have an IDF slightly higher than any existing word and words that exist in every document will have an IDF of zero. Both cases will probably work well with your code.

Comment: Delving further into this issue I found how lucene does it. Lucene uses 1+ in the denominator and before the logarithm, ensuring that the IDF is always positive, but less than one for words contained in every document.

http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html

Comment: Actually i solved the problem by avoiding adding 1+ and by making vector of words for example [0, 3, 1, 0] (since i needed vectors for  calculating VSM) and by doing that i have only calculated TF-IDF for non-zero values. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. :)