# Python (TextBlob) TF-IDF calculation

Tags: python, tf-idf

I've looked at a few methods of calculating TF-IDF scores of words in a document, using Python.  I've opted to use TextBlob.

I'm getting an output, however, they're negative values.  I understand that this is incorrect (a non-negative quantity (tf) divided by (the log of) a positive
quantity (df) does not produce negative values).

I've looked at the following question posted here: [TFIDF calculating confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648599/tfidf-calculating-confusion) but it's been no help.

How I'm calculating the score:

```
 def tf(word, blob):
       return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

 def n_containing(word, bloblist):
       return sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob)

 def idf(word, bloblist):
       return math.log(len(bloblist) / (1 + n_containing(word, bloblist)))

 def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
       return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)
```

And then I'm simply printing out the words with their score.

```
    "hello, this is a test. a test is always good."


   Top words in document
   Word: good, TF-IDF: -0.06931
   Word: this, TF-IDF: -0.06931
   Word: always, TF-IDF: -0.06931
   Word: hello, TF-IDF: -0.06931
   Word: a, TF-IDF: -0.13863
   Word: is, TF-IDF: -0.13863
   Word: test, TF-IDF: -0.13863
```

With the little knowledge I have and what I've seen, it could be that the IDF is not calculated correctly?

All help will be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: log of x if 0<x<1 is negative

Comment: @yurib the values cannot be a negative, because they exist in the document...

Comment: i agree that the tfidf score should not be negative, i'm pointing out that technically, your implementation of it, can return a negative result. for example if a word appears in all blobs then idf() would return log(len(bloblist)/(len(bloblist)+1)) which would be negative.

Comment: @yurib how do i avoid this? because im not sure if its "correct"

Answer (score 2):

Without having an input/output example, it's difficult to pinpoint the cause.
One possibility is the `idf()` method which returns a negative value when `word` appears in every `blob`. This happens because of the `+1` in the denominator which, I assume, is for avoiding division by zero.
A possible workaround could be an explicit check for zero:

```
def idf(word, bloblist):
    x = n_containing(word, bloblist)
    return math.log(len(bloblist) / (x if x else 1))
```

Note: in this case, a word appearing in exactly one blob, or in no blobs at all, would return the same value. There are other solutions to fit your needs - just remember not to take the `log` of a fraction.

Comment: @user47467 then that's exactly the problem i described, you have just one blob so each word appears in 'all' blobs and you take the log of a fraction....

Comment: Your method produces a score of 0 for every word :/

Comment: @user47467 that is the correct tfidf score for the example since you only have 1 document, tfidf makes sense with multiple documents

Comment: even adding another document.. gives incorrect scores. "test" appears in both documents and has a score of 0 whereas the others have a higher score?

Comment: @user47467 that is actually expected, you should read about tf-idf. it's a measure of how important a word is to a document, if a word appears in all documents then it is not important to any specific one.

Comment: but surely, if you're using the term frequency to calculate it and it appears more than any other term, it should have a higher score?!

Comment: @user47467 no, the purpose of tfidf is to normalize intra-document frequency by inter-document frequency. so words like 'the' for example won't show up as very important just because they're used very often. you're using a very trivial example (2 sentences as two documents) so you're getting non intuitive results, but they are correct.

Answer (score -1):

**IDF** scores should be **non-negative**. The problem is in the `idf` function implementation.

**Try this instead:**

```
from __future__ import division
from textblob import TextBlob
import math

def tf(word, blob):
       return blob.words.count(word) / len(blob.words)

def n_containing(word, bloblist):
    return 1 + sum(1 for blob in bloblist if word in blob)

def idf(word, bloblist):
   return math.log(float(1+len(bloblist)) / float(n_containing(word,bloblist)))

def tfidf(word, blob, bloblist):
   return tf(word, blob) * idf(word, bloblist)

text = 'tf–idf, short for term frequency–inverse document frequency'
text2 = 'is a numerical statistic that is intended to reflect how important'
text3 = 'a word is to a document in a collection or corpus'

blob = TextBlob(text)
blob2 = TextBlob(text2)
blob3 = TextBlob(text3)
bloblist = [blob, blob2, blob3]
tf_score = tf('short', blob)
idf_score = idf('short', bloblist)
tfidf_score = tfidf('short', blob, bloblist)
print tf_score, idf_score, tfidf_score
```

Comment: can you explain the tf_score = tf('movie', blob) etc please?

Comment: Sure. Term frequency calculates the occurrence of a word in a document. So it basically counts how many times word movie occurred in document named blob.

Comment: Idf otoh is used to give penalty to words that are very common in all documents. Such as 'the', 'a' etc.